# Como realizar comunicação entre Threads e PySide Qt?

Tags: python, thread, pyqt, pyside

A janela de interface gráfica do usuário criada no PySide é executada normalmente seguindo o fluxo normal do programa. O script python de verdade do programa roda em uma Thread em paralelo. Porém esse script em thread precisa enviar os logs para o QPlainTextEdit da interface gráfica do usuário criada no PySide. Porém ela não aceita receber comandos de threads, o que causa crash da janela. Gostaria de saber como realizar essa comunicação de maneira simples?

Comment: O que quis dizer com "ela não aceita receber comandos de threads"?

Comment: A mensagem é clássica. Creio que se você já tivesse usado PySide certamente teria familiaridade com essa mensagem. A janela só aceita receber comandos em treads iniciados com QThread. Mas não quero usar QThread.

Comment: Se **só** aceita de `QThread` e você **precisa** enviar a mensagem, o que te faz querer não utilizá-la?

Comment: O certo é do Thread enviar sinal para o QThread e o QTread comunica com a janela. Mas não sei nada sobre esses sinais do Qt.

Comment: Tu pode usar os mecanismo do próprio Python, como [isto aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), mas a minha primeira opção seria usar os mecanismos do Qt (signal e QThread).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descubri como:

```
        # Classe de Sinais.
        class Sinais(QtCore.QObject):
            # Elementos.
            elemento1 = QtCore.Signal()
            elemento2 = QtCore.Signal()

            def __init__(self):
                QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        sinal = Sinais() # Instância da Classe Sinais.



        def a():
            print('Bom dia')
        def b():
            print('Boa Noite')

        sinal.elemento1.connect(a)
        sinal.elemento2.connect(b)



        def c():
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                sinal.elemento1.emit()

        tarefa_c = threading.Thread(target=c)
        tarefa_c.daemon = True
        tarefa_c.start()
```